# How to pass options to embedded relation (include)

Tags: active-model-serializers

Using AMS include in a controller like this:

```
render json: user, include: ['notifications']
```

How can I pass options to it? I would like to limit the number of notifications (limit: N) & use an scope for sorting (scope: 'inbox_sorting')